# HTML/CSS issue with aligning floated buttons

Tags: html, css

I just need help with aligning the accept/decline buttons. Because I used float: right; command, the cancel button is thrown to far right side of the boarder, and I don't know any way how I could align it properly.

```
<?php

echo'
<html>
<head>
<style>

p
{ 
    border: 1px solid black; 
    width: 22%; 
    text-align: left
}

label
{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 300px;

    text-align: left;
    padding: 5px;
}

input 
{
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}  


left
{
float: left;
padding: 5px;
}

</style>
</head>
</html>';

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'admin', 'Users');
MYSQLI_SET_CHARSET($conn, "UTF8");

echo '
<FORM ACTION = "Script.php" METHOD = "POST">
    <div>
        <p> 
            <label>Username:    <input type = "TEXT" name = "ID">  </label>
            <br>
            <label>Name:          <input type = "TEXT" name = "name"></label>
            <br>
            <label>Surname:     <input type = "TEXT" name = "surname">  </label>
            <br>    
            <label>Address  <input type = "TEXT" name = "address"></label>
            <br>
            <left><input type = "submit" value = "Accept"></left>
            <input type = "submit" value = "Cancel">
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
        </p>
    </div> 
</form>';

    if(ISSET($_POST["ID"])  && ISSET($_POST["name"])  && ISSET($_POST["surname"])  && ISSET($_POST["address"]))
    {
        $ID = mysql_real_escape_string ($conn, $_post["ID"]);
        $ime = mysql_real_escape_string ($conn, $_post["name"]);
        $priimek = mysql_real_escape_string ($conn, $_post["surname"]);
        $naslov = mysql_real_escape_string ($conn, $_post["address"]);

        MYSQLI_query ($conn, "insert into place ( ID, name, surname, address)
        VALUES (".$id." , ".$name." '.' ".$surname." , ".$address.")");

        if(MYSQLI_AFFECTED_rows($conn) ==0)
            ECHO "Information not added! ";
        else
            ECHO "Information successfully added! ";
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Just a tip, you do realise that you don't have to echo everything out, right? Just write normal html, and then use php when you actually need it.

Comment: It's also bad practice to switch between upper and lower case when using functions (like `echo`). Pick one and stick with it throughout your script.

Comment: Put 'div' container for those buttons. Give width to div container. and make one of your form button as float:left and do not give float to another button.

Comment: I tried all of the proposed solutions, but every time the  buttons are just thrown out of the boarder.

This is how it looks currently, and how I want it to look:
http://i.imgur.com/C3Nin6E.png

Answer (score 2):

Use 
    div style="clear:both;"
or 
    div class="clearifix"

Whenever you use float css.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

before

```
 <input type = "submit" value = "Cancel">
 <input type = "submit" value = "Accept">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

in css

```
.clear
{
clear:both;
}
```